# how to load string value in to array

Tags: objective-c

```
 {
    "north product 1" = "";
    "north product 2" = "";
    "north product 3" = "";
    "north product 4" = "";
}
```

How to load this string from dictionary into to array need to store north product 1,north product 2, north product 3, north produt 4.?

Comment: Do you want the array to be populated by the objects, keys or "object = key"?

Comment: actually iam getting data from dictionary need to store into array!  that array need to store with value like north product 1, north product 2, north product 3 and north product 4.

Comment: @kiran Read NSDictionary documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have no prior experience with the `NSDictionary` class two seconds of actualy looking at the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html) would have given you the answer

```
NSArray *keys = [yourDictionary allKeys];
```

There is also a matching `allValues` method if you decide you want the values and not the keys

Answer (score 0):

Considering I'm not describing any memory management rules.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *nProduct1 = [aDictionary valueForKey:@"north product 1"];
NSString *nProduct2 = [aDictionary valueForKey:@"north product 2"];
NSString *nProduct3 = [aDictionary valueForKey:@"north product 3"];
NSString *nProduct4 = [aDictionary valueForKey:@"north product 4"];

[arr addObject:nProduct1];
[arr addObject:nProduct2];
[arr addObject:nProduct3];
[arr addObject:nProduct4];
```

Comment: i am getting return type has String from dictionary i need to store all the values in to my array....

Comment: NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[CustomValue stringValue:@"North"],nil] ;